# mysql.h file can't be found

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu-12.04, mysql-connector

i'm trying to install connection between c++ and mysql in ubuntu 12.04. i've installed mysql-client, mysql-server, libmysqlclient15-dev, libmysql++-dev. but when i try to compile the code i got the error: `mysql.h there is no such file`. i looked in the folders, there is mysql.h file, i can't understand why it can't find it. here is my code:

```
 /* Simple C program that connects to MySQL Database server*/
    #include <mysql.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    main() {
      MYSQL *conn;
      MYSQL_RES *res;
      MYSQL_ROW row;

      char *server = "localhost";
      char *user = "root";
      //set the password for mysql server here
      char *password = "*********"; /* set me first */
      char *database = "Real_flights";

      conn = mysql_init(NULL);

      /* Connect to database */
      if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
            user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          exit(1);
      }

      /* send SQL query */
      if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          exit(1);
      }

      res = mysql_use_result(conn);

      /* output table name */
      printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
      while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
          printf("%s \n", row[0]);

      /* close connection */
      mysql_free_result(res);
      mysql_close(conn);
    }
```

it's worked, but now i'm facing another error like :

```
mysql.c: In function ‘main’:
mysql.c:21: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
mysql.c:27: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
/tmp/ccinQBp8.o: In function `main':
mysql.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `mysql_init'
mysql.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
mysql.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
mysql.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `mysql_query'
mysql.c:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `mysql_error'
mysql.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `mysql_use_result'
mysql.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row'
mysql.c:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `mysql_free_result'
mysql.c:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `mysql_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `mysql.h` file from the `libmysqlclient-dev` Ubuntu package is located at `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h`.

This is not a standard search path for compilers, however `/usr/include` is.

You'd typically use the `mysql.h` header in your code like this:

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
```

If you don't want to specify the directory offset in your source, you can pass the `-I` flag to gcc (If that's what you are using) to specify an additional include search directory, and then you wouldn't need to change your existing code.

eg.

```
gcc -I/usr/include/mysql ...
```

Comment: I am trying to find the gcc.conf file to add ``-I/usr/include/mysql`` to the search path so syntastic (vim syntax checker) can find the header file. Is this possible/recommended?

Comment: @mattyTpain I'm not familiar with syntastic, but I'd think that it should at least support searching `/usr/include`.  You should do includes with `mysql/mysql.h` so shouldn't require syntastic to search in `/usr/include/mysql`

Comment: Tried adding this and still not having success. I am trying to compile pdo_mysql from source and mariadb-devel package is installed. Full command failing: ```cc -I -I/usr/includ^Cmysql -I. -I/tmp/PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2/include -I/tmp/PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2/main -I/tmp/PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2/pdo_mysql.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_mysql.o
```

Answer (score 41):

just use

```
$ apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

which will automatically pull the latest libmysqlclient18-dev

I have seen older versions of libmysqlclient-dev (like 15) puts the mysql.h in weird locations e.g. /usr/local/include etc.

otherwise, just do a

```
$ find /usr/ -name 'mysql.h'
```

and put the folder path of your `mysql.h` with -I flag in your make file. Not clean but will work.

Answer (score 22):

For CentOS/RHEL:

```
yum install mysql-devel -y
```

Answer (score 7):

this worked for me

```
$ gcc dbconnect.c -o dbconnect -lmysqlclient
$ ./dbconnect
```

-lmysqlclient is must.

and i would recommend to use following notation instead of using -I compilation flag.

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't included the path to mysql headers, which can be found at /usr/include/mysql, on several unix systems I think. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909685/fatal-error-mysql-hno-such-file-or-directory-during-compilation), it may be helpfull.

By the way, related with the question of [that guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687452/mtpain) above, about syntastic configuration. One can add the following to your ~/.vimrc:

```
let b:syntastic_c_cflags = '-I/usr/include/mysql'
```

and you can always check the [wiki page](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki) of the developers on github. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try this gcc -I/usr/include/mysql ****.c -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -o ****

Answer (score 2):

You have to let the compiler know where the mysql.h file can be found. This can be done by giving the path to the header before compiling. In IDEs you have a setting where you can give these paths.

This [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory%20Options) gives you more info on what options to use while compiling.

**To your second problem**
You need to link the libraries. The linker needs to know where the library files are which has the implementation for the mysql functions that you use.

This [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link%20Options) gives you more info on how to link libraries.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using **Eclipse IDE.**

After installing the full MySQL together with **mysql client** and **mysql server** and any **mysql dev** libraries,

You will need to tell **Eclipse IDE** about the following

- Where to find **mysql.h**
- Where to find **libmysqlclient** library
- The **path** to **search** for **libmysqlclient** library

Here is how you go about it.

To Add **mysql.h**

**1**. GCC C Compiler -> Includes -> Include paths(-l) then click + and add path to your **mysql.h** In my case it was **/usr/include/mysql**

[image]

To add **mysqlclient** library and **search path** to where **mysqlclient** library see steps **3** and **4**.

**2**. GCC C Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries(-l) then click **+** and add **mysqlcient**

[image]

**3**. GCC C Linker -> Libraries -> Library search path (-L) then click **+** and add **search path** to **mysqlcient**. In my case it was **/usr/lib64/mysql** because I am using a **64 bit Linux OS** and a **64 bit MySQL** Database.

Otherwise, if you are using a **32 bit Linux OS**,  you may find that it is found at **/usr/lib/mysql**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
yum install mysql
```

It will install mysql client and then

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score -2):

just include the path in your project.cpp file, along with all the included files.

example: include "/usr/local/mysql/include/mysql.h"