# fatal error mysql.h:No such file or directory during compilation

Tags: c++, mysql, compiler-construction

I have the following code

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

when i try to compile it using

```
gcc mysqldb.c -o mysql -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

i get an error saying fatal error mysql.h:No such file or directory. how can i successfully compile and run the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check that `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h` exists. If you have installed the [header files](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) somewhere else (say `/opt/mysql/include`), add that location with `-I/opt/mysql/include.`

Answer (score 14):

I come across the same error today, turn out that I forget to install package `libmysqlclient-dev`. After I install it with

```sh
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

the error went away.

Comment: It's amazing this isn't anywhere else (especially the official doc...)

Comment: Saved my life. Was pulling my hair out over this for the last 2 hours.

Comment: Worked for R as well, running on Conda via WSL Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 11):

I do not know if there is some variation in your operation system. Mine is Arch Linux, and I have installed [mariaDB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MySQL). Within the package, there is a program called 'mysql_config' which can provide the right way of compile your program. By runnig

```
$ mysql_config --help
Usage: /usr/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
    --cflags         [-I/usr/include/mysql]
    --include        [-I/usr/include/mysql]
    --libs           [-L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lssl   -lcrypto -ldl]
    --libs_r         [-L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lpthread -lz -lm -lssl -lcrypto -ldl]
    --plugindir      [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
    --socket         [/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock]
    --port           [0]
    --version        [10.0.17]
    --libmysqld-libs [-L/usr/lib -lmysqld]
    --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
            pkgincludedir [/usr/include/mysql]
            pkglibdir     [/usr/lib]
            plugindir     [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
```

you can see the control flags of the program. With your program, i used the following:

```
$gcc main.c -o main $(mysql_config --libs --cflags)
```

and then, by runnig the the new program 'main'

```
$./main
MySQL client version: 10.0.17-MariaDB
```

which clearly worked out!

So, i'm sure that there a few others ways of doing this, but now this is fine for me.

## Tip

Run the command

```
$mysql_config --libs --cflags
```

to see the exacly flags that mysql_config produces. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but fortunately the command 
`sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev` as specified by 
user4713908 fixed it.

I juat had to specify the path in my makefile as

```
gcc -o database1 chapter5_1.c -I/usr/include/mysql
```

I'm using **Kali Linux**