# Cannot find mysql.h file when installing an R package

Tags: mysql, r

I'm trying to install the RMySQL R library, however, when I try to install it, I get the following error messages:

```
In file included from RS-MySQL.c:22:
./RS-MySQL.h:32:10: fatal error: 'mysql.h' file not found
#include <mysql.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [RS-MySQL.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RMySQL’
```

I have MySQL installed, as I am able to use it with MySQLWorkbench. This ( [fatal error mysql.h:No such file or directory during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909685/fatal-error-mysql-hno-such-file-or-directory-during-compilation)) question seems to be from someone who had a similar problem, however, I'm not sure how to find where the header files were installed -- they are not in either of the paths are suggested. How can I find where my MySQL header files are installed, and then where do I define their path in order to be able to install the RMySQL library?

I am on a Mac and using RStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mysql_config --include
```

I took it from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/115256/where-can-i-find-the-include-files-for-mysql-on-linux) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case today.

I've copied all the headers from `/usr/local/mysql/include` to `/usr/local/include`
and the problem was fixed. If you cannot find your myslq headers, just search the disk for mysql.h

Then there was also an issue of linker not aware of `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`, but 
copying it from `/usr/local/mysql/lib` to the `lib` directory of R fixed it too.