# g++ : missing MySQL library

Tags: c++, mysql, database, ubuntu, g++

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 22.0's MySQL plugin for C++. I attempted to use the following bash commands:

```bash
apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

These commands worked in my previous Ubuntu operating system, but I'm getting the following errors while compiling with g++ in my current operating system:

```cpp
fatal error: mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory
   29 | #include <mysql/mysql.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: What have you tried to figure this out, yourself? Did you try to see if there is a `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h` header file? Did you try and see which files get installed by the `libmysqlcppconn-dev` package? There are commands you can run, you know, that show what gets installed by each package, so, for example, if I were to see that the header files get installed into some non-standard directory that the C++ compiler doesn't search by default I would then know that I must specify the `-I` option when compiling code.

Comment: [https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libmysqlcppconn-dev_1.1.12-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libmysqlcppconn-dev_1.1.12-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html) does not seem to have a mysql/mysql.h file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql.h file can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604228/mysql-h-file-cant-be-found)

Comment: I have verified on my WSL ubuntu install that this file is in the `libmysqlclient-dev`  package using: `dpkg -L libmysqlclient-dev | grep mysql.h` /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev